# getLastKnownLocation() returning null and app not showing under "Recent Location Requests" on emulator

Tags: android, permissions, null, location, runtime

i'm using Android Studio 2.2.3, API 23 (Android 6.0/M) on the emulator and in Studio. I understand that beginning with API 23, you must use Runtime Permissions for methods calling dangerous permissions (ie. ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION in this case). In the code below my getLastKnownLocation() method is returning null (but Provider and LocationManager are not null). Not sure what i'm doing wrong, but i have a feeling it has something to do with how i'm writing the runtime permission. Any insight would be greatly appreciated. Should also note that in my Emulator Location settings, the app does not appear under "Recent location requests".

```
public class MapsActivity extends FragmentActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback, LocationListener {

private GoogleMap mMap;
LocationManager locationManager;
String provider;
Location location;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);
    SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map);
    mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);

    locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
    provider = locationManager.getBestProvider(new Criteria(), false);

    Log.i("Location Manager", locationManager.toString());     //not returning null
    Log.i("Provider", provider);                               //not returning null

    //Runtime permission request
    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "<Explanation of permission request goes here>", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } else {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION}, 1);
        }
    }

    else {
        location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(provider);
        if (location != null) {
            Log.i("Location info:", "not null");
        } else {
            Log.i("Location info:", "null");                   //always returns null, which means the if(ActivityCompat... statement returns false, ie. permission is granted
        }
    }
}


/**
 * Manipulates the map once available.
 * This callback is triggered when the map is ready to be used.
 * This is where we can add markers or lines, add listeners or move the camera. In this case,
 * we just add a marker near Sydney, Australia.
 * If Google Play services is not installed on the device, the user will be prompted to install
 * it inside the SupportMapFragment. This method will only be triggered once the user has
 * installed Google Play services and returned to the app.
 */
@Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
    mMap = googleMap;

    // Add a marker in Sydney and move the camera
    LatLng sydney = new LatLng(-34, 151);
    mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(sydney).title("Marker in Sydney"));
    mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(sydney));
}

@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {

}


@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {

    if (grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        Log.i("Permission", "Permission granted");
    } else {
        Log.i("Permission", "Permission denied");
    }

}
}
```

in the manifests i have:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />
```

Also sidenote, i tried writing a similar code in API 21 as it supposedly does not use runtime permissions, but it still prompt me to include runtime permissions. Anyone know how to bypass this in API 21? would i have to use an earlier version of android studio?

Comment: And? getLastKnownLocation may returns null... Where is the problem?

Comment: how do i get it to not return null? maybe i have to use another method? i'm just trying to get the emulator's location on startup.